# Running complete python application on the cloud

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, cloud, virtualenv

Basically I have built a python application that relies on a few libraries and one windows desktop application.

I wanted to know what the best alternative would be to run this program on the cloud somewhere and be able to run the application remotely from any computer

Is there something available for this?

Thank you

Comment: you can spin up a virtual machine with Windows on GCP. IS that what you're looking for?

Comment: Containerize everything, then you could do what you want easily: VM with cos, gke, could run,...

Comment: Can you please elaborate more? Do you have a link to a tutorial to do this?